# Improve pitch shift

Tags: mplayer, mpv

I've been watching videos using [mpv](https://mpv.io/), a derivative of MPlayer, using the default options. When I increase the speed, pitch-shift kicks in so that while people sound like they're speaking faster, they aren't squeaky and hard to understand like they're on helium.

The pitch-shift (in the manual as **`scaletempo`**) works fairly well, but I've noticed that YouTube does it significantly better.

How does YouTube shift pitch, and is there any way I can improve MPlayer's pitch shift (by tweaking the `scaletempo` options, f.e.)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there is a way to improve mpv, unless you are an mpv developer. Maybe using another player will give better results.

Try using [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) with the `--rate` switch.
VLC uses its own codecs for many formats and is perhaps the world's best
media player.

Comment: I can confirm, that VLC has a better sounding (less stuttering) scaletempo algorithm. I always use mplayer, but if I need to watch a video *much* slower, I use VLC, because it just sounds much more natural.